# Python Query in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get specific country in my dataframe but somehow its producing an error when I add the `and` condition inside the query.

Below is my code.

```
top_country = 15
country_wise_dataframe_temp = country_wise_dataframe.query('Country == "USA" and Country == "Canada"')
fig_confirmed = px.bar(country_wise_dataframe_temp.sort_values('Confirmed').tail(top_country), x = 'Confirmed', y = 'Country',
                      text = 'Confirmed', orientation = 'h', color_discrete_sequence=[cnf])
fig_deaths = px.bar(country_wise_dataframe.sort_values('Deaths').tail(top_country), x = 'Deaths', y = 'Country',
                      text = 'Deaths', orientation = 'h', color_discrete_sequence=[dth])

fig_death_x_confirmed = make_subplots(rows = 5, cols = 2, shared_xaxes = False, horizontal_spacing = 0.14, 
                                     vertical_spacing = 0.1, subplot_titles=('Confirmed Cases', 'Deaths Reported'))

fig_death_x_confirmed.add_trace(fig_confirmed['data'][0], row = 1, col = 1)
fig_death_x_confirmed.add_trace(fig_deaths['data'][0], row = 1, col = 2)

fig_death_x_confirmed.update_layout(height = 3000)
country_wise_dataframe_temp.show()
```

Below is the error message.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-388-e5656e4a8eeb> in <module>
     11                                      vertical_spacing = 0.1, subplot_titles=('Confirmed Cases', 'Deaths Reported'))
     12 
---> 13 fig_death_x_confirmed.add_trace(fig_confirmed['data'][0], row = 1, col = 1)
     14 fig_death_x_confirmed.add_trace(fig_deaths['data'][0], row = 1, col = 2)
     15 

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Basically I just wanted to get the data from all country in USA and Canada.

Comment: One way to do this: `df[(df['Country'] == 'USA') & (df['Country'] == 'Canada')]`

Comment: @S3DEV I tried what you have suggested. And it returns nothing.  But when  I remove canada and only USA remains it display the data that I wanted. And same also happens when I remove USA and add canada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it now. Instead of using and. I should be using or

```
country_wise_dataframe_temp = country_wise_dataframe.query('Country == "USA" |Country == "Canada"')
```